# What C++ projects should I start?

Tags: c++

I'm a high school student, and I have a decent amount of programming experience (HTML, Javascript, PHP, Actionscript 3.0). I know C++, but unlike the other languages I know, I have never actually made any decent sized projects with it. I am puzzled at what kind of project I should start, as there are so many things you can do with C++.

I just want some experience making something - but right now I don't know what I want to do!

HELP ME!

Comment: look in my profile, some things there may interest you perhaps

Comment: Games are fun.  Make one of those.  Card game, tetris, pacman...

Comment: If you list HTML as one of your programming languages, then you probably don't know C++ as well as you think.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should have taken HTML for granted...

Comment: I don't think HTML, considered as a language or not, can be considered as 'granted' ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find some open source projects and offer your help. You get to see other's code and have a goal on what to develop.

**Find something that interests you. That will keep your attention the longest.**

Answer (score 2):

Pick something you're either passionate in, or something that might help you at home.

If you do that, then you have a vested interest in it rather than it being just another application.

For me, I wrote a small system to keep track of my customers.  Now I know there are any number of applications that do that but I just wanted something small and custom so it really worked for me.

After that, when it was working, I then went back and refactored etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question quite often. My reply is always the same. Programming is about scratching an itch. First find something that interests you and doesn't have a solution (or at least a good one). That's the itch.

Next sort out the best solution. It may be C++, .Net, Java or any one of a hundred other languages. The key is to pick the right tool for the job. If you try and push the square language in the round problem you will fail.

Programming is not about any one language. It's about finding the best solution to a problem and implementing it well using the right tools. This is what makes the difference between someone who knows a programming language, and someone who solve problems. The first are a dime a dozen, the second and worth their weight in gold.

Answer (score 1):

Write a bitmap parser and viewer entirely from scratch, don't use any existing libraries. If you want an even bigger challenge, write a jpeg parser, that will require writing a huffman decompression algorithm and all sorts of other goodies.

I did this in java recently for a challenge, the program was rubbish but the amount of things I learnt made it worth while.

Answer (score 0):

You could geek it up and create a complicated RPG (Maybe start with a simple form or console based game to get logic than maybe move on to directx or something).

I made an RPG myself but really never got to directx... yet.  It can be fun because the game can be about whatever you want, your imagination is the only limitation.  Figuring out the logic is a great way to stimulate your brain and learn new techniques in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try and find a copy of The OpenGL Programming Guide and have fun with some graphics programming.  Old editions can usually be had cheaply.

The examples are all in C, not C++, but its good to get some experience in C too.

Also, see if your school or community hosts programming contests.  One of my first large programs was a game for a junior-high level contest (though that was a long, long time ago).